# Find Key of Installed and Activated instance Adobe Acrobat Professional without using 3rd party tools

Tags: adobe-acrobat, serial-number

Have several copies of Acrobat Professional that were purchased previously, installed and activated. However there is no documentation of the serial numbers, the Adobe online account ID or any details for these.

Need to move the licenses to upgraded Windows 7 PCs (current ones are on Windows XP that are about to be decommissioned).

Requirement is to ONLY **move** the licenses to the upgraded workstations. NOT to have multiple instances of the same license running concurrently.

Note: Adobe support is not very helpful since there isn't much information about the licenses.

DO NOT want to use 3rd party tools to extract serial numbers.

Is there a way to get this information from the registry or any other location so that the licenses can be transferred without breaking the activation? If so how?

Comment: Why no third party tools?  (Just asking)

Comment: Many levels of approval is required to use 3rd party tools and there is a lot of hassle with that

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**This is what I was able to find after a few Google searches**

**STEP 1: Find Adobe Key (Encrypted)**

Use one of the methods below.

*M1. Using SQLite DB:*
The activation information is stored at the location below:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Adobe PCD\cache\cache.db

This is a SQLite DB which can be opened with [SQLite Database Browser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser).
Using SQLite Database Browser, you need to look for the key `SN`

*M2. Using the registry:*

For 32 bit OS :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\10.0\Registration\SERIAL

For 64 bit OS :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\10.0\Registration\SERIAL

Replace 10.0 with version of Adobe being used

**STEP 2: Decrypt Key**

Use one of the methods below.

*M1: JavaScript code to decrypt Serial:*

```
function DecodeAdobeKey(sAdobeEncryptedKey)
{
    var regex=/[0-9]{24}/g;
    if(!regex.test(sAdobeEncryptedKey))
    {
        return 'corrupted serial';
    }
    var AdobeCipher = new Array(),index=0,sAdobeDecryptedKey='';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '0000000001';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '5038647192';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '1456053789';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '2604371895';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '4753896210';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '8145962073';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '0319728564';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '7901235846';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '7901235846';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '0319728564';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '8145962073';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '4753896210';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '2604371895';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '1426053789';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '5038647192';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '3267408951';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '5038647192';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '2604371895';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '8145962073';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '7901235846';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '3267408951';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '1426053789';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '4753896210';
    AdobeCipher[index++] = '0319728564';
   
    //decode the adobe key
   for(var i=0;i<24;i++)
   {
       if (i%4 == 0 && i>0)
           sAdobeDecryptedKey += '-';
       sAdobeDecryptedKey += AdobeCipher[i].charAt( sAdobeEncryptedKey.charAt(i) );
   }
   return sAdobeDecryptedKey;
}
```

*M2: PowerShell Code to decrypt Serial*

```
function ConvertFrom-EncryptedAdobeKey {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] 
        [string]
        [ValidateLength(24,24)]
        $EncryptedKey
    )

    $AdobeCipher = "0000000001", "5038647192", "1456053789", "2604371895",
        "4753896210", "8145962073", "0319728564", "7901235846",
        "7901235846", "0319728564", "8145962073", "4753896210",
        "2604371895", "1426053789", "5038647192", "3267408951",
        "5038647192", "2604371895", "8145962073", "7901235846",
        "3267408951", "1426053789", "4753896210", "0319728564"
       
    $counter = 0

    $DecryptedKey = ""

    While ($counter -ne 24) {
        $DecryptedKey += $AdobeCipher[$counter].substring($EncryptedKey.SubString($counter, 1), 1)
        $counter ++
    }

    $DecryptedKey
}
```

*M3: VB Code to decrypt Serial:*

```
Function DecodeAdobeKey(strAdobeEncryptedKey)
Dim AdobeCipher(24)
Dim strAdobeDecryptedKey, i, j
 
AdobeCipher(0) = "0000000001"
AdobeCipher(1) = "5038647192"
AdobeCipher(2) = "1456053789"
AdobeCipher(3) = "2604371895"
AdobeCipher(4) = "4753896210"
AdobeCipher(5) = "8145962073"
AdobeCipher(6) = "0319728564"
AdobeCipher(7) = "7901235846"
AdobeCipher(8) = "7901235846"
AdobeCipher(9) = "0319728564"
AdobeCipher(10) = "8145962073"
AdobeCipher(11) = "4753896210"
AdobeCipher(12) = "2604371895"
AdobeCipher(13) = "1426053789"
AdobeCipher(14) = "5038647192"
AdobeCipher(15) = "3267408951"
AdobeCipher(16) = "5038647192"
AdobeCipher(17) = "2604371895"
AdobeCipher(18) = "8145962073"
AdobeCipher(19) = "7901235846"
AdobeCipher(20) = "3267408951"
AdobeCipher(21) = "1426053789"
AdobeCipher(22) = "4753896210"
AdobeCipher(23) = "0319728564"
 
'decode the adobe key
for i = 0 To 23
if (i Mod 4 = 0 And i > 0) Then
'every 4 characters add a "-"
strAdobeDecryptedKey = strAdobeDecryptedKey & "-"
end if
 
'Grab the next number from the adobe encrypted key. Add one to 'i' because it isn't base 0
j = mid (strAdobeEncryptedKey, i + 1, 1)
 
'Add one to J because it isn't base 0 and grab that numbers position in the cipher
k = mid (AdobeCipher(i), j + 1, 1)
strAdobeDecryptedKey = strAdobeDecryptedKey & k
 
Next
DecodeAdobeKey = strAdobeDecryptedKey
End Function
```

*M4: Java Code to decrypt Serial:*

```
public static String decrypt(String encryptedKey) {
    String[] AdobeCipher = { "0000000001", "5038647192", "1456053789", "2604371895", "4753896210", "8145962073",
            "0319728564", "7901235846", "7901235846", "0319728564", "8145962073", "4753896210", "2604371895",
            "1426053789", "5038647192", "3267408951", "5038647192", "2604371895", "8145962073", "7901235846",
            "3267408951", "1426053789", "4753896210", "0319728564" };

    String sAdobeDecryptedKey = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0 && i > 0)
            sAdobeDecryptedKey += '-';
        String ndx=encryptedKey.substring(i, i+1);
        int tmp=Integer.parseInt(ndx);
        sAdobeDecryptedKey += AdobeCipher[i].substring(tmp, tmp+1);
    }
    return sAdobeDecryptedKey;
}
```

**STEP 3: Download and Install the software with same serial**

Download same version of the Adobe software that was install previously from the official Adobe repository using the links below:

> [Adobe 10, 11](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-downloads.html)
>
> [Adobe 8, 9](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-8-9-product-downloads.html)
>
> [Adobe 7](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/cs2-product-downloads.html#) - Download for Adobe Professional and Standard version 7 and **Serial key available here** - *The serial numbers provided as a part of the download may only be used by customers who legitimately purchased CS2 or Acrobat 7 and need to maintain their current use of these products.* (Can download by using **ANY** Adobe ID to sign in - Not just the Adobe ID it was purchased under)

**References:**

[JavaScript Code](http://pastebin.com/Dvu1Tx9n)

[PowerShell Code](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ConvertFrom-EncryptedAdobeK-1b1160e3)

[VB Code](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/7024747)

[Everything about Adobe’s cache.db (well, not quite)](http://leereid.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/everything-about-adobes-cache-db-well-not-quite/)

[Find Your Adobe Acrobat Serial Number](http://www.electronerdz.com/2012/07/find-your-adobe-acrobat-serial-number/)

Comment: Also a huge thanks for this one. Just a couple of points: In the VB source code, you need to declare `Dim j as Integer Dim k as Integer` Using SQLite Database Browser, you need to look for the key `SN` and copy/paste it into VB/PS/JS program.

Comment: Good catch. Done!

Comment: The link for SQLite Database Browser should be updated to their GitHub repo, which they've moved to in lieu of SourceForge: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser

Comment: This has been updated now

Comment: Wouldn't the DB Browser for SQLite (new name) web site be a better link than GitHub? http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: I love the javascript function - so easy! Just open developer tools in a browser, go to the console, and paste it in. Next step - run the function with the encode key, and out pops the key!

Comment: A Python implementation: https://gist.github.com/fdemmer/dda13fe0d24e44d4b04560c092808c91

Comment: Does this work for CS6?

Comment: @user2060451 I haven't tested with CS6. This is from 4 years ago :)

Comment: Teacher here during the 2020 Corona virus lock down.  Just used this thread to move Acrobat 9 Pro from my puny work laptop to my more powerful PC where I actually teach from.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!