# Find Key of Installed and Activated instance Adobe Acrobat Professional

Tags: encryption, adobe-acrobat

I viewed the following thread:

[Find Key of Installed and Activated instance Adobe Acrobat Professional without using 3rd party tools](https://superuser.com/questions/784578/find-key-of-installed-and-activated-instance-adobe-acrobat-professional-without/786060#786060?newreg=7ed05226964746d597f6e45da12b6309)

I found my encrypted key, but I can't decrypt because I don't where in the Javascript code to paste it. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Key of Installed and Activated instance Adobe Acrobat Professional without using 3rd party tools](http://superuser.com/questions/784578/find-key-of-installed-and-activated-instance-adobe-acrobat-professional-without).  Based on the comments the accepted answer to the duplicate question was the answer, no need to duplicate answers, where one just points out the accepted answer is the answer....

Comment: In order for people to help, they need to understand what is missing or unclear in the accepted answer on the proposed duplicate question.  Please describe exactly how you tried to use it and the results.

Answer (score -1):

In the linked question, the answerer provides a fully functional JavaScript function to decode it which you simply call as `DecodeAdobeKey("yourKey");`, after the function definition.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. First time asking the world to help. I'll try to pay it forward.

Comment: @MattPurucker: If this answered your question, you can accept it to indicate that the problem is solved by clicking the checkmark on the left.