# Find Key of Installed and Activated Adobe Photoshop CS6 Extended without using 3rd party tools

Tags: windows-registry, adobe-photoshop, serial-number

The question is basically the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/784578/find-key-of-installed-and-activated-instance-adobe-acrobat-professional-without), but for Adobe Photoshop CS6 Extended instead of Acrobat.  How do I find the serial number of an installed, activated, running instance *without* third party tools, using only the computer it's running on?  I don't see it in a Windows Registry entry like for the Acrobat key, but maybe I'm not not looking in the right place.  Assume Win7 Pro OS.

Comment: You look at the email Adobe sent you when you purchased it online.  You can look at your Adobe account if you registered the key.  If neither are possible, third-party software will be required, just the way the cookie crumbles.

Comment: Purchased boxed without e-mail address.

Comment: And the license key isn't printed on the box or DVD case?

Comment: @Burgi Probably on the box I didn't keep around for years after successful installation.

Comment: Observing that everything had been working fine for a while, I assumed the license key information had been stored on the computer somewhere.  I'm hoping someone will know where that information is stored, and post directions to find it as an answer.

Comment: If the DVD case has a barcode on it Adobe should be able to provide you with the original key if you send them a photo of it.

Comment: @Burgi They told me they couldn't do anything unless it was purchased with an Adobe ID and I provided credentials for the ID associated with that purchase.