# Javascript, Coding help requested

Tags: encryption, javascript, adobe-acrobat, decryption

To start I am a noob, so explanation of whats happening or what needs to be done to complete the code would be extremely helpful.

I had an issue come up at work, and I found an helpful stack exchange article on a way to remedy my problem. However I can't figure out what to do after I get the code. I have a little coding knowledge, but not enough to figure out whats missing from the code to complete the process. Here is the article: [Find Key of Installed and Activated instance Adobe Acrobat Professional without using 3rd party tools](https://superuser.com/questions/784578/find-key-of-installed-and-activated-instance-adobe-acrobat-professional-without)

In a comment below on the "Answer" @JoBu1324 states that all he had to do was go to the developer tools on a browser, copy and past the code onto the console, then plug in the encrypted key and out popped the decrypted key. However, this is not what I found to be the case as I keep getting a "undefined" error.

I have tried to run the code without pasting the encrypted key in anywhere with no luck and the same "undefined" error. I've tried to create a new variable to store the encrypted key, but it still comes out with the same error. Can anyone help me understand what step I'm missing of where to put the encrypted key so the code will go through the process of Decrypting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the JavaScript solution provided in the linked question you would first need follow the instructions in Step one of the provided answer.  Then  paste the function provided as part of step 2 into the browser and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  You should see `undefined` printed to the screen, which is expected.  You should then type:

```
DecodeAdobeKey('<SERIAL_NUMBER>')
```

Replacing `<SERIAL_NUMBER>` with the value you got from Step 1, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should see the value you need printed to the console. You should then be able to continue with Step 3.

You would need to follow similar steps to use the PowerShell solution.  Paste the PowerShell function into a terminal then type:

```
ConvertFrom-EncryptedAdobeKey -EncryptedKey '<SERIAL_NUMBER>'
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help heavyd! I am still a bit confused sorry to say, How about where in the code do I type that? Above the Function? Or are you saying paste all of the javascript first and then at the very bottom type what you said above with the appropriate encrypted Serial Number?
 or right above the " var regex" ? Or are you saying to replace the <SERIAL_NUMBER> in all of the spots with the variable name sAdobeEncryptedKey is mentioned throughout the code? Sorry, this is where my noob at coding hits the wall.

Comment: Your 2nd option.  Paste in the provided javascript function into the Console tab of your Dev Tools window, then hit "Enter", and it should say `undefined` (that's expected).  Then type `DecodeAdobeKey('<SERIAL_NUMBER>')` but with your actual SN (still in quotes) and hit "Enter".

Comment: Ah, that is something I have not tried, I apologize. I thought the undefined error was the "end" of the program and it had already run its course. Which is why I kept trying to figure out where a line of code must have been missing from within the function. Thanks for clearing that up again! Makes sense to me know.