# Adobe Acrobat X Pro will not open - No Error

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Acrobat X Pro will not open PDFs.

Acrobat installed as part of CS6.

Reader opens the files just fine.

Uninstall and re-install fail.

Found a solution in here that works, but the issue just comes later the same day:

[Adobe acrobat doesn't launch on windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/564948/adobe-acrobat-doesnt-launch-on-windows-7)

The solution was to rename the Cache.db to Cache.old.db.

I was hoping to get some additional leads to fix this issue for good.
Some things I have already tried:

- Kill AV - Repair - Failed to have any effect.
- Kill AV - Rename Cache.db - Keep AV killed for the rest of the week - Issue came back.
- Uninstalled CS6 - Reinstalled - Updated - Issue came back.

Comment: Turns out the issue was with CS6 and not specific to Acrobat.  This solution fixed the issue:  https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/acrobat-failed-launch-30-days.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with CS6 and not specific to Acrobat. This solution fixed the issue:

https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/acrobat-failed-launch-30-days.html

Comment: Can you quote the relevant sections from your link in case it is removed in the future?